# Getting this error only at the second button click? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to do a simple CRUD App in Vue 3 with all the Pokemon Starters of every Generation. So I am displaying Cards with all the Pokemons but when you click on a card then it opens up a modal and you see more info on this specific Pokemon. I have an Arrow down icon in this model, where I want the pokemon to "evolve", so that you can see the evolutions and the information to the evolutions as well.

The problem that I just have is, that the first time I click on the icon, it works fine. But the second time, it is undefined. Can someone help me out please?

Here is the App.vue Code:

```
App.vue

<template>
  <div>Pokemon Starter of every Generation</div>

  <ModalComponent
    :showing="showing"
    :currpkmn="currpkmn"
    @update:currpkmn="currpkmn = $event"
    @close="showing = false"
    class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50"
  />

  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center container mx-auto w-full">
    <CardComponent
      @clickCard="clickCard"
      :pokestarter="pokestarter"
      :showing="showing"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import CardComponent from "@/components/CardComponent.vue";
import ModalComponent from "@/components/ModalComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    CardComponent,
    ModalComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pokestarter: [],
      showing: false,
      currpkmn: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickCard(pkmn) {
      this.currpkmn = pkmn;
      this.showing = true;
      console.log(this.currpkmn);
    },
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      let res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/pokestarter/");
      this.pokestarter = res.data.data;
      console.log(this.pokestarter);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

And here is the Modal component code:

```
ModalComponent.vue

<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div
      v-if="showing"
      @click="$emit('close')"
      class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-75 flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <div
        @click.stop
        class="modal p-12 pt-6 w-1/3 rounded-md"
        :style="{ background: gradient }"
      >
        <div class="modaltitle font-extrabold text-xl">
          Nr.{{ currpkmn.num.toString().padStart(2, "0") }}
          {{ currpkmn.species.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
          }}{{ currpkmn.species.slice(1) }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-10">
          <img
            class="w-32 h-full object-contain p-4"
            :src="currpkmn.sprite"
            :alt="currpkmn.species"
          />
          <p class="text-base font-extrabold mt-4 mb-2">
            Type: {{ currpkmn.types.join("/") }}
          </p>
          <p class="text-base font-bold">Height: {{ currpkmn.height }}m</p>
          <p class="text-base font-bold">Weight: {{ currpkmn.weight }}kg</p>
          <div class="mt-10">
            <p class="text-lg font-bold">
              "{{ currpkmn.flavorTexts[0].flavor }}" - Pokemon
              {{ currpkmn.flavorTexts[0].game }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ArrowDownDropCircle
          class="cursor-pointer mt-10 text-2xl"
          @click="evolve()"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import ArrowDownDropCircle from "vue-material-design-icons/ArrowDownDropCircle.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    ArrowDownDropCircle,
  },
  props: {
    showing: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    currpkmn: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currIndex: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    evolve() {
      let evolutionline = this.currpkmn.evolutionline;

      this.currIndex++;
      console.log("declared variable: ", evolutionline);
      if (this.currIndex === evolutionline.length-1) {
        this.currIndex = 0;
      }
      console.log(this.currIndex);
      console.log("declared variable: ", evolutionline);
      console.log("actual prop: ", this.currpkmn.evolutionline);
      this.$emit("update:currpkmn", evolutionline[this.currIndex]);

    },
  },
  computed: {
    gradient() {
      if (this.currpkmn.types[0] == "Water") {
        return `radial-gradient(circle at center, #acddfe, #2ea1fe)`;
      }
      if (this.currpkmn.types[0] == "Fire") {
        return `radial-gradient(circle at center, #fec3ac, #fe4d2e)`;
      }
      if (this.currpkmn.types[0] == "Grass") {
        return `radial-gradient(circle at center, #d1feac, #2efe5b)`;
      }
      return "white";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.modal {
  font-family: "VT323", monospace;
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

EDIT Added CardComponent Code:

```
CardComponent.vue

<template>
  <div
    @click="clickCard(pkmn)"
    v-for="pkmn in pokestarter"
    :key="pkmn.num"
    class="flex flex-col w-1/6 min-h-fit h-80 mr-5 mb-5 p-2 cursor-pointer overflow-hidden shadow-md rounded-md border-4 border-yellow-400"
    :style="{ background: gradient(pkmn)}"
  >
    <div
      class="title flex justify-between items-center font-bold text-sm text-left"
    >
      <div>
        #{{ pkmn.num.toString().padStart(3, "0") }}
        {{ pkmn.species.charAt(0).toUpperCase() }}{{ pkmn.species.slice(1) }}
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs">
        {{ pkmn.baseStats.hp }} HP {{ pkmn.types.join("/") }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maincontent flex flex-col">
      <div
        class="imgborder flex justify-center container h-32 border-4 border-neutral-100 mb-4 shadow-sm"
        :style="{ background: gradientImg(pkmn)}"
      >
        <img
          class="w-24 h-full object-contain p-4"
          :src="pkmn.sprite"
          :alt="pkmn.species"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="stats">
        <p>Attack: {{ pkmn.baseStats.attack }}</p>
        <p>Sp.Attack: {{ pkmn.baseStats.specialattack }}</p>
        <p>Defense: {{ pkmn.baseStats.defense }}</p>
        <p>Sp.Defense: {{ pkmn.baseStats.specialdefense }}</p>
        <p>Speed: {{ pkmn.baseStats.speed }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    pokestarter: {
      type: Array,
    },
    showing: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  emits: ["clickCard"],
  methods: {
    clickCard(pkmn) {
      this.$emit("clickCard", pkmn);
    },
    gradient(pkmn) {
      if (pkmn.types[0] == "Water") {
        return `linear-gradient(to bottom right, #acddfe, #2ea1fe)` 
      }
      if (pkmn.types[0] == "Fire") {
        return `linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fec3ac, #fe4d2e)` 
      }
      if (pkmn.types[0] == "Grass") {
        return `linear-gradient(to bottom right, #d1feac, #2efe5b)` 
      }
      return 'white'
    },
    gradientImg(pkmn) {
      if (pkmn.types[0] == "Water") {
        return `linear-gradient(to top left, #acddfe, #2ea1fe)` 
      }
      if (pkmn.types[0] == "Fire") {
        return `linear-gradient(to top left, #fec3ac, #fe4d2e)` 
      }
      if (pkmn.types[0] == "Grass") {
        return `linear-gradient(to top left, #d1feac, #2efe5b)` 
      }
      return 'white'
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.imgborder {
  border-color: #E6C68B;
}
</style>
```

Sample of JSON File:

```
    {
      "num": 1,
      "species": "bulbasaur",
      "types": ["Grass", "Poison"],
      "evolutionline": [
        {
          "num": 1,
          "species": "bulbasaur",
          "types": ["Grass", "Poison"],
          "baseStats": {
            "hp": 45,
            "attack": 49,
            "defense": 49,
            "specialattack": 65,
            "specialdefense": 65,
            "speed": 45
          },
          "height": 0.7,
          "weight": 6.9,
          "flavorTexts": [
            {
              "game": "Red",
              "flavor": "A strange seed was planted on its back at birth. The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon."
            }
          ],
          "sprite": "https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani/bulbasaur.gif"
        },
        {
          "num": 2,
          "species": "ivysaur",
          "types": ["Grass", "Poison"],
          "baseStats": {
            "hp": 60,
            "attack": 62,
            "defense": 63,
            "specialattack": 80,
            "specialdefense": 80,
            "speed": 60
          },
          "height": 1,
          "weight": 13,
          "flavorTexts": [
            {
              "game": "Red",
              "flavor": "When the bulb on its back grows large, it appears to lose the ability to stand on its hind legs."
            }
          ],
          "sprite": "https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani/ivysaur.gif"
        },
        {
          "num": 3,
          "species": "venusaur",
          "types": ["Grass", "Poison"],
          "baseStats": {
            "hp": 80,
            "attack": 82,
            "defense": 83,
            "specialattack": 100,
            "specialdefense": 100,
            "speed": 80
          },
          "height": 2,
          "weight": 100,
          "flavorTexts": [
            {
              "game": "Red",
              "flavor": "The plant blooms when it is absorbing solar energy. It stays on the move to seek sunlight."
            }
          ],
          "sprite": "https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani/venusaur.gif"
        }
      ],
      "baseStats": {
        "hp": 45,
        "attack": 49,
        "defense": 49,
        "specialattack": 65,
        "specialdefense": 65,
        "speed": 45
      },
      "height": 0.7,
      "weight": 6.9,
      "flavorTexts": [
        {
          "game": "Red",
          "flavor": "A strange seed was planted on its back at birth. The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon."
        }
      ],
      "sprite": "https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani/bulbasaur.gif"
    },
```

Moved the "evolutionline" variable to data and tried declaring it in a created hook, but did not work.

Comment: Check in your `CardComponent`, when it emits the `clickCard` event, does it pass on an object with a `evolutionline` property?

Comment: @MoritzRingler No the clickCard does not pass it on. I added the Code of the CardComponent, now. Could you maybe check please to see what I can exactly do?

Comment: Did you get it to work? If so and my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted and/or vote for it. Otherwise, let me know what is missing to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was looking in the wrong place initially.

In your `evolve()` method, you emit the pokemon data set in `evolutionline`:

```
methods: {
    evolve() {
      ...
      this.$emit("update:currpkmn", evolutionline[this.currIndex]);
    },
  },
```

This will be the new `currpkmn`. However, that data does not have a `evolutionline` property:

```json
     "evolutionline": [
        {
          "num": 1,
          "species": "bulbasaur",
          "types": ["Grass", "Poison"],
          "baseStats": {
            ...
          },
          "height": 0.7,
          "weight": 6.9,
          "flavorTexts": [
            ...
          ],
          "sprite": "https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/ani/bulbasaur.gif"
        },
```

So next time `evolve()` runs, the prop is undefined and you get the `cannot read property of undefined` error.

I think you need to distinguish between species and pokemon, and `evolve()` should not update species (your `currpkmn` variable), but just the "evolutionary level" (the index).

Something like

```
  <ModalComponent
    :species="currpkmn"
    v-model="evolutionLevel"
  />
```

And then (as an example) you can show stats with:

```
  <StatsDisplay
    v-if="..."
    :pokemon="currpkmn.evolutionline[evolutionLevel]"
  />
```